# Javascript adding timeout to a promise

Tags: javascript

this snippet was extract from Ethan Brown´s book *Learning JavaScript 3rd edition*. Could someone explain, **line by line if possible** what exactly is happening on that function? Specially why are those functions beeing called **using the spread operator**? Couldn´t they just be called with no args at all?

```
function addTimeout(fn, timeout) {
    if (timeout === undefined) timeout = 1000; // default timeout
    return function(...args) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            const tid = setTimeout(reject, timeout,
                new Error("promise timed out"));
            fn(...args)
                .then(function(...args) {
                    clearTimeout(tid);
                    resolve(...args);
                })
                .catch(function(...args) {
                    clearTimeout(tid);
                    reject(...args);
                });
        });
    };
}
```

Comment: This is off topic for Stack Overflow. This site is for debugging specific problems to reach a goal, not discussion or explaining. You should take this to a chat or forum, or maybe softwareengineering.stackexchange.com (although I'm not entirely sure if it's on topic there). Good luck!

Comment: Well, what can I say? This is horrible code.

Comment: line 1, declares a function ... line 18, end of the function ... lines 2 to 17 - absolute garbage that you would be better to disregard if you want to use javascript

Comment: Not all of those `...` s are `spread` operator, some are `rest` operators. And... judging from this example code i think you best throw away that book.